# Prove that $ a $ and $ p$ are coprime if $ p \nmid a $ where $ p$ is a prime and $ a$ is an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Wikipedia's Euclid's lemma statement is as follows:

> Euclid's lemma — If a prime $p$ divides the product $ab$ of two integers $a $ and $b$, then $ p$ must divide at least one of those integers $ a $ or $ b$.

Now at the proof section it is said that:

> The original Euclid's lemma follows immediately, since, if $ n$ is prime, it is coprime with $ a$ if and only if it does not divide $ a$

And proof goes on using Bézout's identity that is  $ as+pt=1$ when $ a $ and  $ p$ are coprime.

It seems like since $ p$ is a prime and $ p \nmid a $ it's automatically the case that $ a $ and  $ p$ are coprime. **But how can one prove it?And also this is not the case if $ p$ isn't a prime. Consider $ a=6$ and $ p=4$.**

**Edit**: Maybe I have found something convincing. Here $ a$ is an integer and $ p$ is a prime. So we can write,
$$ a=1×a=x_1×y_1=x_2×y_2=.......≠p×q [ \text{ since}, p \nmid a \text{ that is, }  a=pq+r] $$
Again, $ {p=1× p} [\text{ since, $ p$ is a prime }]$

So, the only common hence greatest divisor of $ a \text{ and } p $ is 1 , in other words, $ \text{ gcd} (a,p)=1$ meaning, $ a$ and $ p$ are coprime.

Comment: Who says that this holds if $p$ isn't a prime? Of course it is false then.

Comment: Hint: $\gcd(p,a)$ must be a divisor of $p$ ... what are the options?

Comment: By the linked dupe: $\,p\,$ prime, $\,p\nmid a\Rightarrow (p,a)=1\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Is the edited part consistent to be a proof as asked in the title?

Comment: No, it is not correct. It is true (by definition) that $\,p\nmid a\Rightarrow a \neq p k,\,$ but that does not prove what is sought.

Comment: @BillDubuque  You  said it's not correct. But I don't see any problem here. Maybe that edited part is less symbolic. However, what I got to know from possibly duplicate question and your answer there is -        $$ p \mid a \iff    (a,p)=p $$       $$   p \nmid a  \iff    (a,p)=1 $$.    So  according to question since $ p \nmid a $ so $ a$ and $ p$ are coprime. This same thing is present in the edited part more verbally.But you are  saying it's wrong. Please show where is the actual mistake so I can correct myself.

Comment: The text in the edit has no *proof* that $\,p\nmid a\Rightarrow (a,p) = 1.\ $ There is no justification given for the claim "so the only ...." (it is circular proof, i.e. beg's the question).

Answer (score -1):

Since $p$ doesn't divide $a$ then there exist integers $q$ and $r<p$ such that $a=p\cdot q+r$ with $r\neq 0$. So
$$
\gcd(a,p)=\gcd(q\cdot p+r,p)
$$
Suppose by contradiction that $\gcd(a,p)=g>1$ then $g$ divides both $a$ and $p$ so $g=p$ since $p$ is prime. But in this case $p$ has also to divide $a=q\cdot p+r$, namely $p$ has to divide also $(a-q\cdot p)=r$ (we have subtracted a multiple of $p$). So $p$ divides $r$. Contradiction since $r$ is less than $p$ and it is not $0$.

Comment: There's no need to divide with remainder: if $g>1$ then $g\mid p\,$ prime $\Rightarrow g = p,\,$ so $p = g\mid a\ \ $

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).